# How to get email attachment MIME type by file extension?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm trying to write a class that would use [Mandrill APIs](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.JSON.html#method-send) to send an email with an attachment. To do that I need to provide `MIME type of the attachment` for the base-64 encoded attachment contents. The question is how to get it, assuming using the file extension of the attachment?

PS. I was hoping for something better than a long `switch/case` situation. But if that's my only option, where can I get the most exhaustive list of such associations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look in the Registry, under either:

1. `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\<file extension>\` and see if it has a `"Content Type"` value.
2. `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MIME\Database\Content Type\`, enumerating each subkey until you find one whose `"Extension"` value contains the file extension.

There is also a [FindMimeFromData() function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775107.aspx).

If you don't find a matching content type, you can always use `application/octet-stream`.

Comment: Thanks. That's basically all file associations that are installed in the OS, right. For instance, if I don't have a `.pdf` viewer installed, it won't have it in that registry key, correct?

Comment: I'd expect that Windows comes with a PDF entry there by default these days. But fundamentally yes. You'd need to check on a fresh install of Windows to see which ones are built-in. Other apps can add their own though. And I guess the user is unlikely to be handling files they have no viewer/association for.

Comment: @c00000fd There's also the `FindMimeFromData` API which can sniff the data and give you a MIME type without the file extension, although the list of types it recognizes is fairly limited.

Comment: Yes, I just checked on a Windows 7 OS without PDF viewer installed there's no entry for `application/pdf` in that key. Although `FindMimeFromData` looks interesting. Thanks.

Comment: @c00000fd: the Registry's MIME database does not contain all possible file extensions.  But it is also not the only place in the Registry where MIME information is stored.  I updated this answer with another location you can look in.

Answer (score 0):

Apart to what was suggested in a different answer, here's a hard-coded list of file-extension-to-MIME-types associations that I converted from [this Ruby project's](https://rubygems.org/gems/mime-types/versions/2.4.3) JSON list into a C-struct.

Oops, can't post it here. It's too long. [Here's the file](http://forums.codeguru.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=33419&d=1426390785) instead.